# How to directly read the document from a Google Drive and publish the content in text area using PHP or Angular JS?

Tags: php, angularjs, google-drive-api

I am working on a project for blog posting. In the project needs to read the content from the Google Drive document (PDF/DOC/DOCX).

After fetching the content from the doc I need to display the content in textarea for formatting.

How can I do this using PHP or Angular JS?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Google drive is just a file system the drive api isnt going to help you read the file just download and upload them.

Comment: Is any 2 way process to work with google-doc-api?

Comment: There is no google doc api.   there is a google drive api and a google sheets api.

Comment: @DalmTo do you know solution for google drive api

Comment: No the Google drive API does not allow for editing files.  Its just a file system api.